# Changing a recursive condition in a SQL/PHP website menu

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, navigation

I am modifying a site built in PHP with content drawn from a SQL database. The original developer had the navigation created with the following code. It creates the navigation from the CMS pages - it works fine for top level pages but I am trying to modify the way subpages are presented.

What I want it to do is when a subpage is present, it first opens a DIV containing formatting, then populates the subpagemenu by using the 'while' statement below. Finally, when the subpagemenu is finished, it closes the DIV.

I can't seem to work out which condition 'opens' the subpage menu before it goes through the loop of filling out the subpage menu.

Any and all help appreciated - thanks!

```
<?
$pagesrc = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$getPID_sql = "SELECT * FROM tblPages WHERE parentID = 0";
$getPID_result = mysql_query($getPID_sql);
if(!$getPID_result){print mysql_error()."<br />";}else{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getPID_result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  $parentID = $row["pageID"];
  $linkName = $row["pageTitle"];
  $linkID = $row["pageID"];
  print "<A href = '".$pagename."?id=".$linkID."'>".$linkName."</A> | ";
  if($pageID){
    $subpages_sql = "SELECT * FROM tblPages WHERE parentID = $parentID";
    $subpages_results = mysql_query($subpages_sql);
    if(!$subpages_results){print mysql_error();}else{
        $rowcount = mysql_num_rows($subpages_results);
            if($rowcount > 0){
            while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($subpages_results, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $sublinkName = $row2["pageTitle"];
            $sublinkID = $row2["pageID"];
            $sublinkParentID = $row2["parentID"];
            if($sublinkParentID == $pageID || $sublinkParentID == $PID){            
print "<a href='".$pagename."?id=".$sublinkID."'>".$sublinkName."</a>";
            }   
        }   
        }
    }       
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: **Heads up!** Future versions of PHP are *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Comment: Also, you really, really want to keep your indentation and brace use consistent.  Your code is *amazingly difficult to follow* because you misuse indents and don't segregate braces.  Please review [this article on indent styles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) and pick one you like best, then stick with it religiously.  I prefer 1TBS, while some in the PHP community [want to standardize on Allman style](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md).  Icky.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$pagesrc = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$getPID_sql = "SELECT * FROM tblPages WHERE parentID = 0";
$getPID_result = mysql_query($getPID_sql);
if(!$getPID_result){print mysql_error()."<br />";}else{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getPID_result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  $parentID = $row["pageID"];
  $linkName = $row["pageTitle"];
  $linkID = $row["pageID"];
  print "<A href = '".$pagename."?id=".$linkID."'>".$linkName."</A> | ";
  if($pageID){
    $subpages_sql = "SELECT * FROM tblPages WHERE parentID = $parentID";
    $subpages_results = mysql_query($subpages_sql);
    if(!$subpages_results){print mysql_error();}else{
        $rowcount = mysql_num_rows($subpages_results);
            if($rowcount > 0){
                    echo "<div class='submenu'>"; //you can either give class or id whatever you want
            while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($subpages_results, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $sublinkName = $row2["pageTitle"];
            $sublinkID = $row2["pageID"];
            $sublinkParentID = $row2["parentID"];
            if($sublinkParentID == $pageID || $sublinkParentID == $PID){            
print "<a href='".$pagename."?id=".$sublinkID."'>".$sublinkName."</a>";}   
        } 
            echo "</div>";  
        }
    }       
    }
}
}
?>
```

added the  tag where it is requrired

Comment: -1, this is a copy/paste of the original code, but you have not mentioned what you have changed, why you changed it, or how the changes help solve the problem.

Comment: @Charles i have changed the code and as you wanted a description, i have added that description too

Comment: "added the tag where it is required"?  What tag?  Where was it required?  Why was it required there?

Comment: as the question asks, where should he add <div> tag, i've mentioned it. open your eyes please and check

Comment: Okay, so why does it go there?  Explain.  In detail.  In an edit.  **Copy/paste code as an answer teaches *nothing*.**  I realize that this is an amazingly elementary question and answer, but it's pretty much the prime example of how to ask a bad question and get a bad answer.

Comment: Okay @Charles, I'll not copy/paste futher anymore. But earlier, when I answered some questions, they asked where they should use it. That's why I copy their code, made edits and paste them for their convenience